Why are my simple addEventListener functions not working, except one works backwards?
So I'm new to JavaScript and new to coding. I am building a website or two just to learn while I'm building. I'm doing this locally on my laptop. I'm trying to make a button on my website, that when clicked toggles a class name on an element. I did this once already but I'm trying again now, and it just won't work. I've tried a function declaration and an arrow function too. Here are my functions.


const mainMenu = document.querySelector('.button'); 
mainMenu.addEventListener('click', () => { 
  mainMenu.classList.toggle('active'); 
}); 





const mainMenu = document.querySelector('.button'); 
mainMenu.addEventListener('click',  myFunc ()); 
  mainMenu.classList.toggle('active');
} 



If in the declaration function on the addEventListener line I put myFunc() instead of myFunc and then refresh the page, the page loads as if I had already clicked the button which is backward for what I want. If I put myFunc nothing happens at all. What am I doing wrong?
Nothing happens at all. The button doesn't make the menu pop out like I expected. The button should toggle a class on one of my elements, and that class in my CSS is styled to appear once it is toggled on and disappears when it is off. The only time anything happens is if in my function declaration in the addEventListener line, I put myFunc() instead of myFunc. That makes the toggle load already on which is not what I want.

the second argument to addEventListener needs to be a function ... not the result of calling a function, as half your attempts are doing - not sure why the other half are failing - perhaps there's an error in the console when you click the button - or the button is in a form, and clicking it submits the form ... hard to say with no context for the element you click

I tried a function...

myFunc() is a call to the function, not a reference to the function. You want myFunc without ().

I tried that. Nothing happens at all when I don't include the (). When I do include the () the page loads with the function already ran.

without the context of your code, it's hard to say what you're doing wrong (i.e the HTML, when you're loading the JS, etc, any errors in the browser console)

Since you haven't shared your HTML, its hard to say whts wrong

Your problem then most likely is your CSS. .button.active may not do what you expect it to do. Please note that you are trying to toggle the active class on the button being clicked.
